# Why is it considered secure to store a random salt in a database with the user's password digest?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, salt

In the light of the big [LinkedIn password leak](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/646-million-linkedin-passwords-leaked-online/79290), I've been thinking about password security. The web development frameworks that I have worked with in the past typically store a master, application-level salt as an app constant, then salt all user passwords with that value (randomly generated on a per-app basis). e.g. in pseudo-code: `password = hash(App::salt + userPassword)`.

I've read a lot of advice that suggests generating a random salt for each user, then storing that in the database along with each user's password. My question is, how does this increase security? If an attacker procures a list of password digests from the database, they are likely also able to get the salt as well, right? Or is there some attack vector that I don't know of that will get password digests without access to the rest of the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing random salt for each user defeats [Rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack.

In case of a "master salt" it is still possible to precompute such table and use it in the attack. With a per-user salt this becomes impractical.

Comment: Is there any value in having an app-wide salt as well as a random salt then? This would require gaining access to the app config on the file system as well as making the digest more difficult to ascertain from dictionary/common passwords plus the stored salt.

Comment: @rybosome The only issue I can see is that you can't change it in the future without invalidating all current users.